# Async/Await en NodeJS no funciona

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodejs, async, async-await

Estoy con un inconveniente para devolver un resultado dentro de una función async que tiene un ajax con un await dentro. Probé con 3 librerías ("**http**", "**request**", "**then-request**").

La idea básicamente es que al terminar el ajax, se retorne la respuesta de la misma; sin embargo, devuelve *undefined* (**no respeta el async/await**).

---

Archivo: **index.server.js**

```
const PyService = require("../../../api/services/PyService/validacionCSV");

module.exports = {
    pasajeClientes: async function (matcheos) {
        let resultado = await PyService.validate(matcheos);
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

---

Archivo: **validacionCSV.js**

```
const request = require('then-request');

module.exports = {

    validate: async (matcheos) => {

        var response;

        await request("GET", `${process.env.API_URL}/validate`, {
            json: {
                csv: {
                    clients: "datosPersonas.csv",
                    products: "movimientos.csv"
                },
                primary_keys: {
                    clients: "ID",
                    products: "ID",
                },
                branches: {
                    products: "rama",
                },
                rules: {
                    clients: matcheos["clientes"],
                    products: matcheos["productos"],
                }
            }
        }).done((resultado) => {

            let matched = resultado.ok;
            let no_relationships = resultado.no_relationships;
            let repeated = resultado.repeated;
            let total = resultado.total;
            let type_errors = resultado.type_errors;

            response = { 
                error: false,
                message: "",
                errorConTipoDatoClientes: type_errors.clients,
                errorConTipoDatoProductos: type_errors.products,
                errorConClientesSinProductos: no_relationships.clients,
                errorConProductosSinCliente: no_relationships.productos,
                errorConClientesRepetidos: repeated.clients,
                errorConProductosRepetidos: repeated.products,
                cantClientesOk: matched.clients,
                cantProductosOk: matched.products,
                cantClientesEnArchivo: total.clients,
                cantProductosEnArchivo: total.products,
            }

            if (no_relationships.clients > 0 || no_relationships.products > 0
            ||  repeated.clients > 0 || repeated.products > 0
            ||  type_errors.clients > 0 || type_errors.products > 0
            ) {
                response.error = true;
                response.message = "Los clientes/productos importados poseen errores."
            }
            else
                response.message = "Los clientes/productos importados no poseen errores."

        });

        return response;
    }
}
```

Esto por algún motivo (como dije anteriormente) devuelve *undefined* en vez de un json object. Si tienen alguna consulta al respecto, me avisan y les respondo.

Comment: Podrías probar implementando promise o callbacks. No respeta el await por que lo que intentas efectuar es asíncrono.

Comment: No conozco la librería, pero ese `done` me hace pensar que no es una `Promise` estándar. Creo que si la llamada falla la función que le pasas no se ejecuta. Además la librería es antigua... ¿por qué no usar Promesas normales?

Comment: @MatiasNavarro, intenté utilizar callbacks y promesas, pero en ambos casos sigue devolviendo undefined.

Comment: @PabloLozano, la librería "then-request" a diferencia de "request" supuestamente sirve para hacer un request síncrono, pero por lo visto tampoco funciona, es decir, hacer el request, pero también devuelve undefined.
En todos los casos que probé fue siempre guardando la respuesta en una variable (que luego es retornada).

Answer (score 0):

Debes retornar response en este caso dentro de .done al final:

```
.done((resultado)=>{
     response = ...;
     ...
     return response;
});
```

Al parecer lo de .done es una promise, por lo tanto debes retornar algo dentro de ella, cosa que no estas haciendo y por eso luego te devuelve undefined.

Tambien tener en cuenta que cualquier asignación que este dentro de una promise, en este caso nuestro:

```
.done(()=>{...})
```

Se queda dentro de la promise, es decir, dentro de ella la asignación se hace, pero fuera del cuerpo de la promise, no se realizan cambios a la variable.

Lo otro es que nunca estas almacenando el resultado de ejecutar la función request dentro de en este caso la variable response, por esto tambien es lógico que el resultado sea undefined... ya que nunca se le hace realmente una asignación a la variable response:

```
var response; //Undefined
...
...
... fuera de .done:
return response; //Retornas undefined ya que nunca le asignas nada a esta variable.
```

Entonces lo que deberias hacer es lo siguiente:

Quitarle el await a la función request (no necesitas el await):

```
request(()=>{...});
```

A la variable response, asignarle el resultado de la ejecución de la función request, si te da problemas poner la variable al inicio, ponla al final:

```
var response = await request(...);   //Con los parametros que requieras usar.
```

Retornar la respuesta dentro del .done al final:

```
.done(()=>{
   ...
   ...codigo
   return response;
})
```

Por ultimo, retornar la respuesta dentro de la función validate y fuera de la función done al final, luego de haber asignado a la variable, la ejecución de la función request:

```
validate: async((matcheos)=>{

    ...
    ...
    response = await request(...);
    return await response;

})
```

Este devolvera una promise en la que puedes usar ya sea await en otra función asincrona para obtener el valor:

```
let resultado = await PyService.validate(matcheos);   //Json resultado
```

O simplemente usar then para realizar dentro de este las operaciones donde necesitemos del valor traido de la promise:

```
PyService.validate(matcheos).then((val)=>{

   //Operaciones a realizar con val.

});
```

Comment: Esto de las promises enreda un poco xd, espero sea de ayuda la respuesta, pruebala a ver si sirve de algo...

Comment: Mmmm nop, tampoco, de hecho seguí paso a paso de lo que mencionaste y directamente no corría el request.

Comment: debe haber otro metodo que captura errores (como el catch de las promises), deberias añadirlo y ver si te retorna algo.

Answer (score 0):

Si ese request devuelve una promesa (y más vale, pero nadie usa done sino then) no veo el sentido de tu await. Sólo retorna el request y dentro de él retorna response. Asi como lo tienes ahora es una promesa que resuelve a undefined. De paso tu await no espera nada en particular